# clearing memory of dynamic object instances sometimes slow, sometimes fast, EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My EXCEL VBA code builds up 1500+ instances of complex objects, always with good speed.
After all data have been processed my code cleans up, i.e. all objects and collections of them are getting set to NOTHING.
Sometimes this clean-up is fast (~10s), sometimes slow (>5 minutes).

I never start this code multiple times in the same session, i.e. I always close the workbook (all workbooks) and make sure Excel is closed.
There are no conditional formattings.
Screen updating is set to FALSE.
I use MS Office Professional Plus 2016.

Does anybody have an idea why it sometimes is fast and sometimes slow?

As some code is asked for here's the upper level clean-up loop for the superItems collection:

```
For idx = 1 To superItems.Count
    Application.statusBar = thisFunction & ": " & superItems.Count - idx & " items left"
    Set superItem = superItems(idx)
    If Not (superItem Is Nothing) Then
        superItem.clear
        Set superItem = Nothing
    End If
    DoEvents
Next idx

Set superItems = Nothing
```

... and here's the method superItem.clear:
the superItem object holds an array (pArrTmxxItems) with pointers to item objects.

```
ub = UBound(pArrTmxxItems)
For idx = 0 To ub
    Set item = pArrTmxxItems(idx)
    If Not (item Is Nothing) Then
        item.clear
        Set item = Nothing
    End If
Next idx
```

... item.clear looks like this:
the item object holds a collection pCAs of CA object instances, and (b) a collection pChildren of its own kind (i.e. aChild is of the same class as item)

```
If Not (pCAs Is Nothing) Then
    For idx = 1 To pCAs.Count
        Set CA = pCAs(idx)
        If Not (CA Is Nothing) Then Set CA = Nothing            'jp171107
    Next idx
    Set pCAs = Nothing                                          'jp171107
End If

If Not (pChildren Is Nothing) Then
    For idx = 1 To pChildren.Count
        Set aChild = pChildren.item(idx)
        aChild.clear
        Set aChild = Nothing
    Next idx
    Set pChildren = Nothing                                     'jp171107
End If
```

Comment: Hi - you need to include some of your code in the question.

Comment: How are these `pChildren`, `pCAs`, `superItem` declared? Are these public variables? (If so, the code has bad architecture.) If they are private variables declared within a sub, you should not be taking care to set them the Nothing, the `VBE` will do it for you.

Comment: pChildren and pCAs are private collections of object ITEM.
supterItems is a collection and yes, it's a public variable - I'll try to change that.
superItem is a class object. the instances are created dynamically, so I call their method clear to set all of its collections pCAs and pChildren to nothing after callling the collections objects CLEAR method.

Comment: what happens if you just close the workbook without clearing?

Comment: if the code skips the clean-up it 
(a) shows the same fast/slow effect as if it executes the clean-up ("Not responding" for minutes), and...
(b) sometimes crashes ("Excel has stopped working...") after these minutes, or when trying to save and close the workbook.

Comment: Just a small remark: in VBA, iterating a Collection by index is rather inefficient. It is preferable to use a For Each loop, which uses the Collection's own iterator.

Comment: yes, agreed - thanks!
does it make the code faster? will test.

Answer (score 0):

1. Redeclare all the public variables. Every single one of them, except for the constants. Take care of the scope and do not pollute it.
2. Delete all the part of the code, setting stuff to nothing. The VBA Environment will do it for you. Automatically.

Comment: after changing at least that one global variable 'superItems' (a collection) to a local one it looked promising. but now it's just happening again...
Thanks anyway!